# SQL Server 2014 SQL Job CmdExec and access denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, sql-server-agent, jobs

I have a little trouble with SQL Agent Job.

It should execute program in network directory like `\\x\y\z.exe`.

Job Step uses proxy account with credentials of a user, which can full access that directory.

Unfortunately job still can't access network directory with error:

> Access is denied

If I set permission on directory to `Everyone`, there is no problem. Do I miss something?

I am using a UNC path. `xp_cmdshell` is enabled. Proxy account is fine. I am using it also to run SSIS packages, which doesn't show any problems.
`CmdExec` subsystem is set to proxy Account
Sharing and UAC permission on directory is set properly.

Is it because SQL Agent job is using not supported authentication type to access directory?

Comment: Is the user setup properly for **both** security _and_ share permissions on the shared folder?  If you add the account to only the security access list or the list of users who can access the share, but not both, this error can occur.

Answer (score 2):

When you configure a Proxy account, you have to check "CmdExec" subsystem in order to use CMDExec with this Proxy Account.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have issues with the proxy account. Either it is not configured properly or make sure only the sysadmins can exec `CMDExec`.

See:

- [Permission to execute CMDEXEC](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=35882) (sqlteam.com forum thread)
- [Access Denied error when running job in SQL Server Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394623/access-denied-error-when-running-job-in-sql-server-agent) (Stack Overflow Q & A)

Comment: Proxy account is fine. I am using it also to run SSIS packages, which doesn't show any problems.